# Как вывести описание подкатегории woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

Ситуация такая: есть магазин на wordpress, при переходе на продукты в меню переходит на страницу woocommerce, где отображены подкатегории товаров. Отображены в виде картинки и заголовка. Не знаю, как вывести краткое описание подкатегории. Вот сам файл, подскажите, какой код влепить, чтобы было краткое описание категорий.

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product category thumbnails within loops.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product_cat.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce_loop;

// Store loop count we're currently on
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;

// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) )
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );

// Increase loop count
$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;
?>
<li class="product-category product<?php
    if ( ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0 || $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 1 )
        echo ' first';
    if ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] == 0 )
        echo ' last';
    ?>">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $category->slug, 'product_cat' ); ?>">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
        ?>

        <h3>
            <?php
                echo $category->name;

                if ( $category->count > 0 )
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
            ?>
        </h3>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );
        ?>

    </a>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category ); ?>

</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

я использую код

> <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

Comment: В каком файле вы прописываете это? Я прописал в вышеприведенном файле, и не сработал код...

Answer (score 1):

Вывод описания категории в карточке категорий:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'custom_add_product_description', 12);
function custom_add_product_description ($category) {
    $cat_id        =    $category->term_id;
    $prod_term    =    get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
    $description=    $prod_term->description;

    echo '<div class="category-description">'.$description.'</div>';
}
```